# How would I calculate how much of a mesh's volume intersects with another mesh

Tags: c#, game-physics, game-development, godot4

So, I'm making a game in Godot, and unfortunately it lacks any means of doing this on its own, or even a rough estimate of this using the collision meshes, so since I have to do this manually, I'm going to at least have some fun with it!

I'm doing this for buoyancy calculations, because I want to have as accurate simulations as I reasonably can for this. The mesh/collider needs to be able to rotate, so an AABB is out of the picture, since I intend to have this on the player - who can swim - as well.

More than likely I'll end up using the collision shape rather than the actual mesh for this, since it's a good enough approximation and an easier calculation, but if it doesn't bog down much at all, I would love to have this as accurate as possible.

I've tried AABBs and estimating based on the player's center of mass, but both options aren't really good due to lack of accuracy, and inability to tell if the hitbox is rotated or not.

I'm entirely stumped so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage using collision shapes because:

- They are (often) simpler than the actual mesh.
- We can use the physics APIs to query them.

Of course, a first approximation would be if the collision shapes collide or not. You might also be able to iterate over the AABB of one of the objects and check for collisions with the other at some fixed intervals (either intersecting a point, or intersecting a box collision shape).

See for example: [Detect intersections between an `AABB` and a `CollisionShape3D`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/207059/10408)